# No such field found: field java.lang.String sinput error when accessing cppcheck plugin classes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

]I am a junior dev trying to lear about Jenkins, I have been learning on my own for a couple of months. Currently I have a pipeline (just for learning purposes) which runs static analysis on a folder, and then publish it, I have been able to send a report through email using jelly templates, from there I realized it is posbile to instantiate the classes of a plugin to use its methods so I went to the cppcheck [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/cppcheck/) and did some trial and error so I can get some values of my report and then do something else with them, so I had something like this in my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('analysis') {
            steps {
                script{
                    bat'cppcheck "E:/My_project/Source/"  --xml --xml-version=2 . 2> cppcheck.xml'
                }

            }
        }
        
        stage('Test'){
            steps {
                script {
                    publishCppcheck pattern:'cppcheck.xml'
                    
                    for (action in currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions()) {
                        def name = action.getClass().getName()
                        if (name == 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.cppcheck.CppcheckBuildAction') {
                            def cppcheckaction = action
                            def totalErrors = cppcheckaction.getResult().report.getNumberTotal()
                            println totalErrors
                            def warnings = cppcheckaction.getResult().statistics.getNumberWarningSeverity()
                            println warnings
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
   
    }

}
```

which output is:

```
[Pipeline] echo
102
[Pipeline] echo
4
```

My logic (wrongly) tells me that if I can access to the `report` and `statistics` classes like that and uses their methods `getNumberTotal()` and `getNumberWarningSeverity()` respectively, therefore I should be able to also access the `DiffState` class in the same way and use the `valueOf()` method to get an enum of the new errors. But adding this to my pipeline:

```
def nueva = cppcheckaction.getResult().diffState.valueOf(NEW)
println nueva
```

Gives me an error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field org.jenkinsci.plugins.cppcheck.CppcheckBuildAction diffState
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:425)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:409)
...
```

I can see in the [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/cppcheck/) there is a `diffState` class with a `valueOf()` method, but I cannot access to it is therre any other way to get the new errors between the last build and the current one?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues that could be causing this:

1. `CppcheckResult` doesn't have a member variable `diffState` so you can't access it obviously

If you check the javadoc of [CppcheckResult](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cppcheck-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/cppcheck/CppcheckResult.java) the class does have:

```
private CppcheckReport report;
public CppcheckStatistics getReport()
```

and

```
private CppcheckStatistics statistics;
public CppcheckStatistics getStatistics()
```

there is no member (and getter method) for `diffState` so maybe try to call:

```
/**
 * Get differences between current and previous statistics.
 * 
 * @return the differences
 */
public CppcheckStatistics getDiff(){
```

my suggestion: `cppcheckaction.getResult().getDiff().valueOf(NEW)`. Furthermore [CppcheckWorkspaceFile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cppcheck-plugin/blob/1063171ec14a4826982976c80b29b8dbf0253fee/src/main/java/com/thalesgroup/hudson/plugins/cppcheck/model/CppcheckWorkspaceFile.java#L123) does have a method `getDiffState()`.

---

2. Please have a look at the script approval of your Jenkins (see [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/)).

The syntax error might appear because Jenkins (Groovy Sandbox) blocks the execution of an (for the Jenkins) "unknown" and potential dangerous method.

Jenkins settings - Script Approval - Approve your blocked method

Comment: thx for answering, I had already tried `cppcheckaction.getResult().getDiff().valueOf(NEW)` before and I got `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: NEW for class: groovy.lang.Binding`, regarding the script approval I had done it too as I needed some approvals for the other methods too. I have been checking `CppcheckWorkspaceFile` but as I have never worked with Java and having little experience I do not see how to access to it in my pipeline...could you give an example of how the stntax would be for `getDiffState` in a pipeline? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have also updated the main question with the image of the ```CppcheckDiffState``` class and the ```valueOf()``` method that I have seen in the javadoc